# Can android service has permission to create directory and write files in external storage public directory

Tags: android, service

Can and Android service running in background create directory in external storage public directory. If yes how to do it please share sample code.
However I am getting permission denied even after adding permit in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

On Android 10 and above, have a look at the scope storage feature.

Source:- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage